# Delete records based on array list - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have struggled a lot untill I reached this step. Basically, finally after certain criteria, I have an array with the ID's that I should remove from the DB.

This is the code that I have:

```
var ListOfIdThatNeedToBeRemoved = {id's};
```

I also have a table persons, that has PersonID. The persons I wish to delete is contained in ListOfIdThatNeedToBeRemoved variable.

I also have:

```
dbContext.tbl_persons
```

Any insight is appreciated :)

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework, and depending on the version, you could use [RemoveRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(dbContext context = new dbContext())
{
    context.tbl_persons.RemoveRange(context.tbl_persons.Where(x => ListOfIdThatNeedToBeRemoved.Contains(x.id)));
    context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do something similar to:

```
using(dbContext context = new dbContext())
{
   foreach(var ID in ListOfIdThatNeedToBeRemoved)
   {
      context.tbl_persons.RemoveRange(context.tbl_persons.Where(x => x.id == ID));
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```